# Javascript Code not printing today's date but yesterday

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var value_ = "2017-06-01";

value_ = value_.split(".")[0];
value_ = value_.replace(" ","T");
var dateObject = new Date(value_);

formattedDate = (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObject.getDate() + "/" + dateObject.getFullYear();

alert(formattedDate);
```

[JSFiddle here:](https://jsfiddle.net/qcdekacp/)

It's printing wrong date, why?

Comment: `Date.parse` doesn't know how to interpret your input string. It's inverting the month and day since `06-01` is ambiguous (is the date June 1st or January 6th?).

Comment: It's converting the date (which it interprets as UTC) to your local time zone. See the dupe.

Comment: @AndréDion It's June 1st.

Comment: Why are you trying `.split(".")[0]` and `.replace(" ","T")`?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Because in some cases I am using the same code and I have date value in the form of timestamp and Internet Explorer doesn't parse milliseconds and shows NAN

Comment: @Dan It's June 1st... somewhere in the world, but not everywhere.

Comment: @JosephMarikle True. What would be the best thing to do then?

Comment: @Dan, no, it's both. `2016-06-01` is June 1st if your input string is formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, but it's January 6th if your format is YYYY-DD-MM.

Comment: @AndréDion That's not how the Date constructor parses dates. All, please read the duplicate I commented. It shows how to remedy this situation.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Is correct.  The solution in this case would be to pass three parameters to a `new Date()` object (adjusting for the month offset).

Comment: Try [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/), some [examples here.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/momentjs/1982/getting-started-with-momentjs/18251/general-usage#t=201706021642370210783)

Answer (score -1):

If you have to construct a date object from a string, use **[`Date.parse();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** with the string in the correct format. Don't pass the string directly to the `Date()` constructor.

```js
// Use correct string format (this assumes that you have no control over the
// string's format).
var dateString = "2017-06-01";

// That format could be invalid, so we need to correct it.
var dateObject = new Date(dateString.replace("-", " "));

console.log("The date is: " + dateObject);

formattedDate = (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObject.getDate() + "/" + dateObject.getFullYear();

console.log(formattedDate);
```

However, if you want the current date, just instantiate a new date with no parameters:

```
var today = new Date();
```

Comment: Explain the down vote please.

Comment: I  didn't downvote, but it's using the Date constructor on a string, not as numbers, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I was trying to fix my timestamp related issue since that was not included in the answer. So, now, this code works in IE 11 and it shows NAN in Chrome.  https://jsfiddle.net/439rwgk3/

Comment: @Dan You are doing too much manipulation to the string. This works: https://jsfiddle.net/73tye5cg/1/

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for answer. But that doesn't works in IE 11. It shows NAN and that's why I was manipulating

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print today's date, here is one approach:

```
var dateObject = new Date();

formattedDate = (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObject.getDate() + "/" + dateObject.getFullYear();

alert(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Please type out the entire word, don't use "text-speak" (If *you* want to print today's date....)

Comment: Also, that's not the question the OP is asking.

Comment: why downvote ? i answer right.